# Plain Text Break Lines with Transchoice in Twig(Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm programming a Plain Text mail version for that I need \n for new lines.

Almost everything works but I have a problem with the transchoice filter, as I said before the break lines are being printed as text and not as break line

foo.twig.txt

```
{{ 'Foo.plain.intro'|transchoice(nr, {'%nr%': nr, '%name%': entity.name}) }}
```

messages.en

first try:

```
Foo.hello.test: '{1} Hello %name% \n there is one test found. \n See you later. | ]1,Inf[ Hello %name%, \n  there are %nr% tests found. \n See you later.'
```

After the first try the output for one element was:

```
Hello tester \n there is one test found. \n See you later.
```

Second try:

```
Foo.hello.test:  "{1} Hello %name% \n there is one test found. \n See you later. | ]1,Inf[ Hello %name%, \n  there are %nr% tests found. \n See you later."
```

Second output:

```
{1} Hello tester
there is one test found.
See you later.
```

Third try:

```
Foo.hello.test:  '{1} "Hello %name% \n there is one test found. \n See you later." | ]1,Inf[ "Hello %name%, \n  there are %nr% tests found. \n See you later."'
```

Third output:

```
&quot;Hello tester \n there is one test found \n See you later.&quot;
```

I also tried changing the twig part including the raw filter:

```
{{ 'Foo.plain.intro'|transchoice(nr, {'%nr%': nr, '%name%': entity.name})|raw }}
```

For the third try, including the raw filter the output is:

```
"Hello tester \n there is one test found \n See you later."
```

Is there are form that something like that would work, for normal translation strings the translation has to have double quotes to recognize \n:

messages.en

```
Foo.hello: "Hello %name%, \n see you later"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `|` to indicated the line breaks.

```
Foo.hello: |
  Hello %name%, 
  see you later
```

Read **[yaml format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html)**.

Comment: thank you for the answer but sadly it didn't work with transchoice